# Cloudera Visualization Tool

Tags: hadoop, data-visualization, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, graph-visualization

I need to know if **cloudera** is providing any visualization tool. I found that we can connect to **tableau** or **zoomdata** for visualization but are they giving any visualization tool of their own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera ships a Hadoop ecosystem component called [Hue](http://gethue.com/), which is basically a GUI for doing various types of exploration on Hadoop data (SQL queries, natural-lang search, etc.). It includes some lightweight visualization features, but nothing as robust as you would get from Tableau or Zoomdata.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

You have some additional options such as:

1. **Apache Zeppelin** - http://zeppelin.apache.org/
2. **jupyter** - http://jupyter.org/
3. **beaker-notebook** - https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook
4. **rodeo** - https://github.com/yhat/rodeo
5. **RStudio** - https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/ (if you like R)

Comment: Are these options open source or paid ? which one among them are best ?

Comment: These are all free, RStudio has an enterprise version. Zeppelin and jupyter would be the two to look at first i would think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: FYI, among all these options, only Hue is supported by Cloudera (if commercial support is a concern).

Comment: @JustinKestelyn Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I really like the philosophy of Apache Zeppelin. It blend different technologies into one notebook. So that users can choose different technologies comfortable with for different purpose.

Here are few tasks which can be done.

- Import file using Shell (like curl)
- Analyze using with Spark
- Visualize. [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) is glue I added to support Highcharts for spark.
- Publish report

Comment: Thanks for the help !